# numpy pandas not working in IDLE / work in Anaconda

Tags: numpy, pandas, anaconda, python-idle

I am running Python 3.5.1 on Windows 10 and have Anaconda and IDLE installed.
If I run any Python files, pandas and numpy seem to work in Jupyter notebooks, but not in IDLE.
I have ensured that the PATH and PYTHONPATH environment variables include access to the folders where pandas and numpy are located (Lib/site-packages).
I receive the following error in IDLE when trying to import pandas:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

When I try to import numpy I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray'
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Odd.  1. Is Anaconda3 the only python installed on the machine?  2. (related) Does `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\idlelib` exist, and contain about 60 `.py` files?  3. If you run `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python` and enter `import numpy` at the prompt, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
I had the same problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637960/6376603

maybe the above answer will help.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I uninstalled anaconda from my system completely. 
Steps - Delete app, delete anaconda3 folder, empty trash

Then I reinstalled older version of it and it started working perfectly. Maybe it is some kind of bug in the newer version.