# import numpy not working in IDLE

Tags: python, numpy

I have python3.5.2 installed on a windows10 machine(Adding into the pythonpath is included in the setup with new python). I ,then, installed the Anaconda(4.2.0) version. At the command prompt when i run the python interpreter and `import numpy` it works fine. But when i save it as a script and try running from the IDLE, it gives

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pramesh\Desktop\datascience code\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from numpy import *
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'`

I don't know what the problem is. I donot have any other python version installed.

Comment: Run `import sys` then `sys.version_info` in both the command prompt and IDLE to compare the versions. This will help verify that there is no other python on your machine.

Comment: make sure you are not running python2 idle.

Comment: Also, it is possible you do have python. One in the traditional "bin" directory, and another under the Anaconda directory. So be on the look out for this.

Comment: @YoussefG. how do i make sure i'm not using python2 idle?

Comment: @nbryans they printed out the same output

Comment: Yeah, it's possible they have the same version, but there are still two installations. That's why I added my second response :)

Comment: @nbryans could you elaborate on how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You *do* have two versions of python installed: the CPython 3.5.2 distribution you mention first, and the Anaconda 4.2.0 Python distribution you then mention. Anaconda packages a large number of 3rd party packages, including Numpy. However, the CPython 3.5.2 installation available on python.org only ships with the standard library.

These two python installs have separate package installations, so having Anaconda's numpy available doesn't make it available for the CPython install. Since you're starting the Idle with shipped with CPython, which doesn't have numpy, you're seeing this error. You have two options:

- Install numpy for CPython. See numpy documentation for details on how to do this, but it may be difficult.
- Use the version of Idle included with Anaconda. This should be available in the Anaconda programs folder.

Comment: did you mean IDE included with Anaconda or IDLE? And it seems there are two copies of same python version. Any solutions for using IDLE with numpy packages?

Comment: I meant IDLE, since you specifically asked about it, and as far as I know Anaconda ships IDLE along with everything else they ship. That said, most of the people I know do use Anaconda also use Spyder (the IDE Anaconda ships) rather than IDLE.

Comment: Thanks, yes i thought you meant Spyder so wanted to clear it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pip in Anaconda Command Prompt, cd to C:\Anaconda\Scripts, and use pip from there.

after that, you can use pip command.
[image: pip install fuzzywuzzy]

just instead of fuzzywuzzy install numpy there. 
that'll surely work

Comment: This will probably work for OP, but they should be aware that there machine likely has two python installations.

Comment: yeah, that also maybe the case.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `python -m` before pip command, so that you won't get any problem while doing so in IDLE..
ex. `python -m pip install scipy/numpy`